# Wix - Use NTVersion64 in a variable to determine operating system bitness

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need to determine the user's operating system architecture in my installer to show it in the title of my bootstrapper. $(var.Platform) does not work as the bootstrapper is x86, and always returns "x86". I've had some success using `NTVersion64` to differentiate between 32 and 64 bit in order to install the correct .msi by using it in the install condition like so:

```
<Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="x64" DisplayName="name (64-bit)" InstallCondition="VersionNT64" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)name-win10.Installer\bin\Debug\name-Debug-x64.msi"/>
      <MsiPackage Id="x86" DisplayName="name (32-bit)" InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT64" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)name-win10.Installer\bin\Debug\x86\name-Debug-x86.msi"/>
</Chain>
```

I had the idea to use `VersionNT64` to define my own variable to use so I can write something like the following and then access the defined variable in my bootstrapper project:

```
<?if $(var.VersionNT64) = "true"?>
    <?define OSArchitecture = "x64"?/>
<?endif?>
```

This does not work however as it cannot find the variable $(var.VersionNT64) Can anyone tell me how I can use `NTVersion64` to check whether the .msi is running on a x86 or x64 system?

Answer (score 4):

statements are preprocessor statements and are evaluated at build time.  They aren't used at runtime.

The VersionNT64 and Not VersionNT64 conditions you mentioned are the correct ways to know if you are 64bit or 32bit at install time.